# Why can't the aop execute when a method is called from anonymous class' method?

Tags: java, aspectj, anonymous-inner-class

Here is my custom annotation `AnnoLogExecTime` and class `AOP`:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface AnnoLogExecTime {

}

@Aspect
@Service
public class AOP {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AOP.class);

    @Around("execution(@com.judking.general.aop.AnnoLogExecTime * *(..))")
    public Object calExecTime(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable        {
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature();
        Method method = signature.getMethod();

        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object obj = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        logger.info("method `"+method.getName()+"` takes "+(t2-t1)+"ms");
        return obj;
    }
}
```

And the test case is as below:

```
@Service
class A    {
  public void go()  {
    B b = new B()  {    //Anonymous class B
      @Override
      public void exec()    {
        aopMethod();
      }
    };
    b.exec();
  }

  @AnnoLogExecTime
  public void aopMethod()    {
    System.out.println("aopMethod");
  }
}

@Service
class B    {
  public void exec()    {
    System.out.println("exec");
  }
}
```

When I call `a.aopMethod()`, the `AOP.calExecTime` is hooked up to `a.aopMethod()`.

But if I call `a.go()`, which is using anonymous class `B` instance to call `a.aopMethod()`, then the `AOP.calExecTime` is **NOT** hooked up to `a.aopMethod()`.

Could anyone give me an explanation to this phenomenon? And please give me a way to resolve this problem in the case of anonymous class. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly because it is an anonymous inner class. **What you are experiencing is a limitation of AOP proxies.**

When you have

```
A a = ...; // get proxy
```

The proxy itself wraps the actual instance in a wrapper instance. When you interact with this wrapper instance by calling

```
a.aopMethod();
```

the proxy interceptor intercepts the call and can execute the advice.

This would apply to you calling

```
a.go()
```

if there was a joinpoint. Instead nothing intercepts that call, and the call to `go()` goes through the interceptor and the method is called on the actual instance

```
actualA.go();
```

When you create the anonymous inner class and have

```
@Override
public void exec()    {
    aopMethod();
}
```

it's implicitly doing

```
@Override
public void exec()    {
    A.this.aopMethod();
}
```

which goes around the proxy because you are calling it on the actual instance, not the wrapper.

You might not be using Spring to generate your proxies, but [their documentation explains this pretty well.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies)